# Добавление текста в поля в цикле

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, tkinter, список

Помогите, пожалуйста. Пишу цикл для стирания и вывода значений в текстовые поля, должна получиться такая конструкция в итоге (если делаю так вручную, то все работает)

```
self.num0.delete(0.0, END)
self.num0.insert(0.0, row[0])

self.num1.delete(0.0, END)
self.num1.insert(0.0, row[1])

self.num2.delete(0.0, END)
self.num2.insert(0.0, row[2])

self.num3.delete(0.0, END)
self.num3.insert(0.0, row[3])
# И так еще много раз
```

Делаю цикл:

```
range1 = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 11]

for x in range1:
   self.num[x].delete(0.0, END)
   self.num[x].insert(0.0, row[x])
```

Но он почему то не работает. Пишет мол `AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'num'`

Answer (score 4):

Я не самый крупный специалист в питоне, но здравая логика подсказывает, что запись типа:

```
self.num0
```

Это обращение к атрибуту с именем num0.

А запись типа

```
self.num[0]
```

это обращение к нулевому элементу массива, на который должен ссылаться атрибут **num**.
А его и нет, к чему и ошибка.

То есть ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```
self.num[0].delete(0.0, END)
self.num[0].insert(0.0, row[0])

self.num[1].delete(0.0, END)
self.num[1].insert(0.0, row[1])
```

То есть эти "текстовые поля" в коде, где они у вас там создаются должны присваиваться не к num0, num1 ..., а нужно сперва инициализировать массив с именем num, а потом уже ему присваивать или добавлять элементы.

Как это корректно написать на Питоне - не знаю, ввиду незнания питона.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас именование полей num0, num1, num2... Естественно, что при обращении num[0], num[1] возникает ошибка.